# MySqlDataReader.GetSchemaTable ColumnOrdinal is +1 of the actual data

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm trying to use the ordinal value to pull data from each row of a `MySqlDataReader` instead of using the string lookup.  In order to do this I'm using the `GetSchemaTable` that is available from the reader to get a data table to loop through for filling out a dictionary that uses the column name as the key and the ordinal as the value.  However the values in the data table are +1 of the actual position of the columns in the reader.

Example:
I have a sql statement that returns records with the schema -

```
EventID, StreamUrl, CreatedStamp, ModifiedStamp
```

The `GetSchemaTable()` method from the `MySqlDataReader` is mapping those columns as -

```
EventID = 1, StreamUrl = 2, CreatedStamp = 3, ModifiedStamp = 4
```

But the way the data reader is presenting the data is -

```
EventID = 0, StreamUrl = 1, CreatedStamp = 2, ModifiedStamp = 3
```

Code:

```
Dictionary<string, int> _columns = new Dictionary<string, int>(35, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

DataTable _dt = _reader.GetSchemaTable();
foreach (DataRow _row in _dt.Rows)
{
    _columns.Add((string)_row["ColumnName"], (int)_row["ColumnOrdinal"]);
}
```

I've used this exact code against `IDataReader` in other projects and have not seen this happen.  Why would there be a mis-match between the schema table's ordinal value and the readers actual ordinal value?

Edit:
MySQLConnector Version - 8.0.11 From NuGet
.Net Version - 4.6.1

Comment: Are you saying that if you look the table that results from SqlDataReader.GetSchemaTable()  and from MySqlDataReader.GetSchemaTable(), the column ordinals are off-by-one?  Somehow that doesn't surprise me.  There are differences between SqlDataReader.GetSchemaTable() and if you just gin up a DataReader on some in memory data (though not this off-by-one issue).  This code was written by two different teams belonging to two competitors.  One team thought 0, 1, 2 made a lot of sense (since it would be consumed in C#) and the other thought 1, 2, 3 made sense, well, because...

Comment: Yep that is exactly what I’m seeing.  Seems like the code review process for the pull request failed in a major way. Thanks for clarifying it was two different teams that wrote the code. I may cast it back down to an IDatabaseReader and see if it corrects the problem.

Comment: Doing a simple cast won't fix it.  It's the implementation, not the type.  I wrote some code that used a datareader's schema table and a some reflection to build an ORM mapper.  I ended up doing special-casing based on the underlying type of the datareader (though it wasn't quite this extreme).  I see below that it's a known bug.  Unfortunately, a fix would be a breaking change (think about it).  Don't hold your breath waiting for a fix.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug in MySQL Connector/NET: [bug 61477](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61477). According to that bug report, it's unlikely to be changed due to backwards compatibility concerns.

If you stick with Connector/NET, you'll just have to manually subtract one from the ordinal value. Otherwise, you can switch to [MySqlConnector](https://mysqlconnector.net/), which [fixes this bug](https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/#fixed-bugs).